# Create a NSString of objects from an NSMutableArray with Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with core data objects. I want to create an `NSString` with these objects formatted in this way:

> **Keyword - Definition**
>
> **Keyword - Definition**
>
> **Keyword - Definition**

I have the following code to gather one index from the array:

```
Term *term = [self.terms objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ \r\n", term.keyword, term.definition];
```

I am not exactly sure how to loop this so that every index from the array has been added to the string all together. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you _tried_ to solve this on your own? If so, what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
for (Term *term in self.terms) 
{
       [string appendFormat: @"%@ - %@\r\n", term.keyword, term.definition];
}

//at this point "string" contains keywords and definitions of all terms
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
for(Term *term in self.terms)
 {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ \r\n", term.keyword, term.definition];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Term *term in self.terms) {
   // Note: This string is only visible in the scope of the loop, define it elsewhere if you wish to do something with the string outside of the loop

   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ \r\n", term.keyword, term.definition];
   // Do something with string.
}
```